# Why was Zoe incompatible with Cole?

Tags: zoe-2018

In the movie *[Zoe](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6010628/)*, when Zoe checks her compatibility with Cole, the answer is **0%**. When Zoe asks why is the score so low, the machine answers that there is a "*fundamental incompatibility*". Later Cole explains that the score was so low because

> she's a synthetic.

In what way does this explain their incompatibility?

Comment: Does  "companion" include having a family and raising children, or is it just friendship and (presumably) sex?

Comment: According to the movie, synthetics are created to be a perfect partner for humans, so most likely it includes romantic relationship and sex and friendship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer, having assessed Cole's mental state and emotional makeup seems to have determined that *he was fundamentally incapable of having a fulfilling relationship with a synthetic being*, especially one that he had a major hand in creating.

> **Cole:** *... But I can't unsee some of the ways I've seen you, in the beginning. In some ways I think it makes me even more in awe of who you are now.*

His inability to look past the fact that she's not a 'real person' means that he's unable to invest fully in any relationship. This is brought into sharp relief when she has an accident and he's forced to return her to a non-emotional robotic state.

> **Ash:** *There's a line, Zoe. Humans on one side, machines on another. And you were on his side of the line until tonight*

Note that **the computer isn't assessing their emotional or sexual compatibility**, both of which are presumably quite high, **but the likelihood of them having a successful long-term relationship** (noting that it may also have taken into account that as a prototype she has a limited shelf-life).

That all being said, once he's grown as a person and been able to manage to see beyond his prejudice and once she's become sufficiently self-aware as to value and defend her own existence, their compatibility would presumably rise dramatically if it was to be re-assessed.